# Responsive Navigation SharePoint 2013 Collapse Issue

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, navigation

I am using sharepoint 2013 navigation the problem is in mobile Version when user open the menu the and taps on the child item the the parent item collapes and gets clossed. I looked out for this solution i found two urls but some how both are not working does anyone know any other workaround to make it work for mobile devices.

The Links i tried are as under. 
http://artykul8.com/2015/04/sharepoint-navigation-and-mobile/
http://artykul8.com/2015/04/sharepoint-navigation-and-mobile/